# yarn - installation of deasync fails

Tags: node-gyp, node-deasync

When I create a react app on Windows with node 15 like this:

```
yarn create react-app my-project --template typescript
```

It fails with

```
yarn create v1.22.11
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.0.6: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.0.6" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
[-/4] ⠁ waiting...
[-/4] ⠁ waiting...
[3/4] ⠂ deasync
error C:\Users\teyc\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\deasync: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node ./build.js
Arguments:
Directory: C:\Users\teyc\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\deasync
Output:
C:\Users\teyc\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\deasync>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
gyp info using node@15.0.1 | win32 | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.7.3 found at "C:\Users\teyc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.8.30717.126) found at:
```

I don't want to install compilers. Are there binaries available for downloading?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the deasync node package might not contain every binary for your node version and operating system, and `yarn` for some inexplicable reason requires it when running `create react-app` while `npx` doesn't.

Your options are:

1. Figure out how to download the prebuilt binaries into your system

https://github.com/abbr/deasync-bin

2. use `npx`

```
npx create react-app my-project --template typescript
```

3. use [yarn 2](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started). This is the method I prefer as it consumes less disk space

```
yarn set version berry
yarn create react-app myproject --template typescript
```